# Using Clang with OpenMP Offloading to NVIDIA GPUs

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2017, clang, openmp

I wrote a simple c code, and I would like to offload it to GPU in windows 10. I installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and latest release clang from https://releases.llvm.org/ and CUDA 10.1. I used this command to compile the code:

```
>clang -pedantic -Wall -o ompGO test.c -fopenmp=libomp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda -lc -lcudart -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\lib\x64" --cuda-path="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1"
```

But I keep getting weird errors like:

```
clang: warning: No library 'libomptarget-nvptx-sm_35.bc' found in the default clang lib directory or in LIBRARY_PATH. Expect degraded performance due to no inlining of runtime functions on target devices. [-Wopenmp-target]
test.c:40:2: warning: no newline at end of file [-Wnewline-eof]
}
 ^
1 warning generated.
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdio.h:12:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:48:
In file included from C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\10.0.0\include\vadefs.h:18:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vadefs.h:28:33: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
        typedef unsigned __int64  uintptr_t;
                                ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdio.h:12:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:10:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:83:1: error: expected identifier
_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:76:29: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER'
        __pragma(pack(push, _CRT_PACKING))
                            ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vadefs.h:14:22: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_PACKING'
#define _CRT_PACKING 8
                     ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdio.h:12:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:10:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:83:20: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER
                   ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:180:29: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
    typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
                            ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:283:51: error: unknown type name 'uintptr_t'; did you mean 'intptr_t'?
        void __cdecl __security_check_cookie(_In_ uintptr_t _StackCookie);
                                                  ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:182:30: note: 'intptr_t' declared here
    typedef __int64          intptr_t;
                             ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:284:9: error: '__declspec' attributes are not enabled; use '-fdeclspec' or '-fms-extensions' to enable support for __declspec
      attributes
        __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl __report_gsfailure(_In_ uintptr_t _StackCookie);
        ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:284:67: error: unknown type name 'uintptr_t'; did you mean 'intptr_t'?
        __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl __report_gsfailure(_In_ uintptr_t _StackCookie);
                                                                  ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:182:30: note: 'intptr_t' declared here
    typedef __int64          intptr_t;
                             ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:288:8: error: unknown type name 'uintptr_t'; did you mean 'intptr_t'?
extern uintptr_t __security_cookie;
       ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:182:30: note: 'intptr_t' declared here
    typedef __int64          intptr_t;
                             ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:296:1: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
_CRT_END_C_HEADER
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:79:23: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_END_C_HEADER'
        __pragma(pack(pop))
                      ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdio.h:12:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:12:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:76:9: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER'
        __pragma(pack(push, _CRT_PACKING))
        ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdio.h:12:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:279:10: error: '__declspec' attributes are not enabled; use '-fdeclspec' or '-fms-extensions' to enable support for __declspec attributes
_ACRTIMP __declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl _invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn(void);
         ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:281:1: error: '__declspec' attributes are not enabled; use '-fdeclspec' or '-fms-extensions' to enable support for __declspec attributes
__declspec(noreturn)
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:287:16: error: unknown type name 'uintptr_t'; did you mean 'intptr_t'?
    _In_       uintptr_t _Reserved);
               ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:182:30: note: 'intptr_t' declared here
    typedef __int64          intptr_t;
                             ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdio.h:12:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:561:13: error: unknown type name 'size_t'; did you mean 'time_t'?
    typedef size_t rsize_t;
            ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:551:28: note: 'time_t' declared here
        typedef __time64_t time_t;
                           ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h:2010:1: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
_CRT_END_C_HEADER
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:79:23: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_END_C_HEADER'
        __pragma(pack(pop))
                      ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdio.h:13:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h:13:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_stdio_config.h:12:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER
^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vcruntime.h:76:9: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER'
        __pragma(pack(push, _CRT_PACKING))
        ^
In file included from test.c:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdio.h:13:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h:31:14: error: unknown type name 'FILE'
_ACRTIMP_ALT FILE* __cdecl __acrt_iob_func(unsigned _Ix);
             ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h:49:17: error: unknown type name 'FILE'
        _Inout_ FILE* _Stream
                ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_wstdio.h:58:17: error: unknown type name 'FILE'
        _Inout_ FILE*   _Stream);
                ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

The code is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <omp.h>

int main (){



    const int N = 1000;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
    float *a;
    float *b;
    float *c;

    a = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    b = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    c = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
        //srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
        b[i] = ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * 4.0;
        c[i] = ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)) * 4.0;
    }

    #pragma omp target data map (to: c[0:N], b[0:N]) map(tofrom: a[0:N])
    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        a[j] = b[j]+3.73*c[j];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if anybody could help me. Apparently, there is error even in including stdio.h. I should highlight that I can compile c codes with clang but when I want to use OpenMP and GPU I got these errors.

Comment: I have a feeling this application will be orders and orders of magnitude slower than just a straight `for` loop, if you got it to compile that is.

Comment: @Blindy I think it makes sense For large N as shown [here](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/gpu-programming-with-openmp/)

Comment: It's an interesting paper, but I'll quote the author himself from underneath the graph you're referencing, "The GPU triad operation is dominated by memory transfers between CPU and GPU. There is a very minimal compute part on GPU and hardly any overlapping of computation and communication. Though GPU compute part could finish very quickly, the overall application performance doesn’t benefit by GPU compute power."

Comment: BTW, it is only a test code to check whether everything is ok or not.